# MEAN stack - User-Post association

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mean-stack

I have two mongoose schemas, user and post. I made connections between them with:

```
{ type: schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }.
```

But how DB is going to know which user creates new post. I know about populating post with "author" but still whose id will be appended to post ?

I finished authentication part, you can login, there is a token in local storage..

Does token in localStorage have something with that on front-end part ? If someone has an example of blog application, user-post association..

Comment: That would depend entirely on how you've implemented the authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set all your references by yourself.

For exemple, to create a new post with an associated user, you have to do something like this:

```
new Posts({
    date: new Date(),
    content: 'My Post content',
    userId: yourUserId // Here you set your user reference
}).save();
```

And then, to get your posts with associated users, you do:

```
Posts.find().populate('userId').exec(function(err, posts) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(users); // Here you get your posts with users if exists
});
```

Hope it helps.